# How can I log debug messages to a file for Flutter without using Flutter packages inside VS Code?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, debugging, logging, console

I would like to pass all debug console data from VS Code to a .txt file, without impacting any of VS Code features provided with flutter extension. It would be great to simultaneously pass data to file and print in embedded console.

I'm not interested in using packages to create file. ChatGPT gave me solution but it works just from terminal

```
flutter run > log.txt
```

I tried to pass it as argument for launch.json, but without success.

```json
{
    "name": "With txt logging",
    "request": "launch",
    "type": "dart",
    "program": "flutter",
    "args": ["> log.txt"],
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

[The VS Code docs for launch configs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_redirect-inputoutput-tofrom-the-debug-target) state:

> If the debugger extension you are using can run the debug target in VS Code's Integrated Terminal (or an external terminal), you can try to pass the shell redirect syntax (for example, "<" or ">") as arguments.

Try adding `"console": "integratedTerminal"` to your launch config. If that doesn't work, then I think this is not supported by the Dart/Flutter extension.